# How to make an image fit the size of a jumbotron

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have an image which I want to display in a jumbotron. The image doesn't fit 100% in the jumbotron. It is clipped. How do I make an image fit 100% in the jumbotron

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid myphoto-section bg-myphoto-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-welcome">
                <h1>Welcome to MyPhoto</h1>
                <p>Photos you can cherish!</p>

            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.myphoto-section {
    min-height:500px;
}

.bg-myphoto-dark {
    background-color: #504747;
    color:white;
}

.bg-myphoto-light {
    background-color: white;
    color: #504747;
}

.jumbotron-welcome {
    background-image: url('../images/fathersday1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    color:white;
}
```

I tried following code which worked but the jumbotron's size is not adjusted proportional to image's size.

```
 <div class="container-fluid myphoto-section bg-myphoto-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
                <img src="images/fathersday1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                <h1>Welcome to MyPhoto</h1>
                <p>Photos you can cherish!</p>

            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to fit an image to size of the jumbotron programatically or do I need to create images of same size as the jumbotron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
.jumbotron-welcome{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

This should make the image take the whole width and height of the jumbotron.

Comment: It worked but the image looks horrible I suppose the safest best is to create image of size of the screen

Comment: Yep, it will strech the image.